# How to resolve Tabdrop bootstrap issue?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-tabs

I use bootstap Modal and Bootstrap tabs and i want to achieve the tabdrop, when the Modal window loads the tabs are not grouped even they overflow `$('.nav-tabs').tabdrop({text: "More"});`  but when i resize the browser window it works, what could be the problem in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issues, but as i can see on demo site it is working ok, maybe the problem is with your other scripts. Try to add this only on tablest, like this

```
var width = $(window).width(), height = $(window).height();
if (width <= 768) {
$(window).trigger('resize');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use **setTimeOut** to call **TabDrop** method. It will work in all browsers.
>   No need to call resize manually.

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('.sub-categories').tabdrop({
     text: "More"
   });
},100);
```